# I can not detect the USB device with Android USBManager

Tags: android

I am trying to use the UsbManager of Android, but it does not find the device connected to the USB.
I am testing on the emulator android, connected one card reader and want to control the reading of data, only that my app can not read if there is a device connected to the USB port.

Anyone had this problem?

```
        UsbManager mUsbManager = (UsbManager)GetSystemService(Context.UsbService);

        int countdevice = mUsbManager.DeviceList.Count;

        DeviceList = mUsbManager.DeviceList;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this card reader normally work with your computer? Perhaps a driver needs to be installed first?

On the other hand, have you listed an intent for the USB device manager:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
</intent-filter>
```

It would be helpful if you posted the error message you get.